# Is there any existing code to create a depth averaged Dfs2 file from a Dfs1 file?

Tags: mikeio

I would like to use model outputs from a MIKE21fm model in DFS1 format to create a depth averaged DFS2 file to be used as boundary conditions in a MIKE3fm model.

For each timestep, every layer should use the depth averaged data from the DFS1 file at that timestep.

I have noticed there is already an existing function for converting DFS2 files into DFS1 files in MIKEIO,  `dfs2todfs1`, however I wondered if there was any existing MIKEIO code/functions to create DFS2 files from DFS1?

I am currently trying to carry this out myself in Jupyter Notebooks however I thought I would ask first as it looks like there has already been lots of useful work in MIKEIO already!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no function in MIKE IO to do exactly this, but you can try something like this.

```py
import numpy as np
from mikeio import Dataset, Dfs1, Dfs2
dfs = Dfs1("mikeio/tests/testdata/tide1.dfs1")

ds = dfs.read()
wl = ds['Level']
wl2d = np.expand_dims(wl, 1) # 1d -> 2d

newds = Dataset([wl2d], time=ds.time, items=ds.items)

dfs2 = Dfs2()
dfs2.write("tide2d.dfs2", newds, dy=1.0, coordinate = ["UTM-32", 0, 0, 0.0])
```